# Jmeter flexible file write header issue

Tags: jmeter

[image: I had to use Flexible File Writer with the following config]

But in CSV file first response is getting clubbed with headers, what wrong I am doing I here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're opening the right file? I cannot reproduce your issue using:

1. [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with 2 users/loops
2. [JSR223 Sampler to set variables values using the following Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code:

   ```
   vars.put('id', 'KCO0000')
   vars.put('reqId', UUID.randomUUID().toString())
   ```
3. [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) configured like:

   - Header

     ```
     endTimeMillis,responseTime,latency,sentBytes,receivedBytes,isSuccessful,responseCode,id,reqId
     ```
   - Entry:

     ```
     endTimeMillis|,|responseTime|,|latency|,|sentBytes|,|receivedBytes|,|isSuccessful|,|responseCode|,|variable#0|,|variable#1|\r\n
     ```

Demo:

[image]

Full test plan just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4.1">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">2</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Some Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">vars.put(&apos;id&apos;, &apos;KCO0000&apos;)
vars.put(&apos;reqId&apos;, UUID.randomUUID().toString())</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.FlexibleFileWriter guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.FlexibleFileWriterGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.FlexibleFileWriter" testname="jp@gc - Flexible File Writer" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="filename">testResults.txt</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="columns">endTimeMillis|,|responseTime|,|latency|,|sentBytes|,|receivedBytes|,|isSuccessful|,|responseCode|,|variable#0|,|variable#1|\r\n</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="overwrite">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="header">endTimeMillis,responseTime,latency,sentBytes,receivedBytes,isSuccessful,responseCode,id,reqId
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="footer"></stringProp>
        </kg.apc.jmeter.reporters.FlexibleFileWriter>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Yes I am using the same config, which might be the reason I am using ULTIMATE THREAD GROUP and JSON extractor , things work when I remove header